# Mapstruct: exclude all field by superclass

Tags: java, dto, mapstruct

I have standard entities and dto's.

Entities:

```java
public class Type extends DefaultEntity {
  int id;
  String name
  ...
}
            
public class Attribute extends DefaultEntity{
  int id;
  String name; 
  Type type;
  ...
}
```

and DTO's

```java
public class TypeDto extends DefaultDto {
  int id;
  String name;
  ...
}
        
public class AttributeDto extends DefaultDto{
  int id;
  String name; 
  TypeDto type;
  ....
}
```

when I create this `Mapper`:

```java
@Mapper
public interface AttributeDtoConverter {
  AttributeDto convert(Attribute source);
}
```

Mapstruct generates:

```java
public class AttributeDtoConverterImpl implements AttributeDtoConverter {
    
  @Override
  public AttributeDto convert(Attribute source) {
    if ( source == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    AttributeDto attributeDto = new AttributeDto();

    attributeDto.setId( source.getId() );
    attributeDto.setName( source.getName() );
    attributeDto.setCode( source.getCode() );
    attributeDto.setType( typeToTypeDto( source.getType() ) );

    return attributeDto;
  }

  // Here is the problem
  protected TypeDto typeToTypeDto(Type type) {
    if ( type== null ) {
        return null;
    }

    TypeDto dictionaryDto = new TypeDto();

    typeDto.setId( type.getId() );
    typeDto.setName( type.getName() );

    return typeDto;
  }
}
```

I want to exclude from mapping all properties of target object if they are subclasses of `DefaultDto` (or exclude all properties of source object if they are subclasses of `DefaultEntity`).

I know I can exclude every property by name `@Mapping(target="type", ignore=true)`, but for large classes with much more dependencies it will we very annoying. And changing model with this approach becomes hell.

Can I somehow exclude all properties by their superclass?

**Update**
I tried `@Condition`:

```java
@Mapper
public interface AttributeDtoConverter {
  AttributeDto convert(Attribute source);

  @Condition
  default boolean needToMap(Object value){
    return ! (value instanceof DefaultDto || value instanceof DefaultEntity);
  }
}
```

It works but I don't like how the generated code looks like:

```java
public class AttributeDtoConverterImpl implements AttributeDtoConverter {
    
    @Override
    public AttributeDto convert(Attribute source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        AttributeDto attributeDto = new AttributeDto();

        if ( needToMap( attributeDto.getId() ) ) {
          attributeDto.setId( source.getId() );
        }
        
          if ( needToMap( attributeDto.getName() ) ) {
            attributeDto.setName( source.getName() );
        }
        if ( needToMap( attributeDto.getCode() ) ) {
          attributeDto.setCode( source.getCode() );
        }
        if ( needToMap( attributeDto.getType() ) ) {
          attributeDto.setType( typeToTypeDto( source.getType() ) );
        }

        return attributeDto;
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will work for your use case, because the solution is global, not specific to a certain mapping, but probably a good approach would be using a custom `MappingExclusionProvider`.

The [Mapstruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-exclusion-provider) indicates:

> MapStruct offers the possibility to override the `MappingExclusionProvider`
> via the Service Provider Interface (SPI). A nice example is to not allow
> MapStruct to create an automatic sub-mapping for a certain type, i.e.
> MapStruct will not try to generate an automatic sub-mapping method for an
> excluded type.

For example:

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.lang.model.element.Name;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;

import org.mapstruct.ap.spi.MappingExclusionProvider;

public class CustomMappingExclusionProvider implements MappingExclusionProvider {
    private static final Pattern JAVA_JAVAX_PACKAGE = Pattern.compile( "^javax?\\..*" );

    @Override
    public boolean isExcluded(TypeElement typeElement) {
        Name name = typeElement.getQualifiedName();
        return name.length() != 0 && ( JAVA_JAVAX_PACKAGE.matcher( name ).matches() ||
            name.toString().equals( "your.pkg.DefaultDto" )||
            name.toString().equals( "your.pkg.DefaultEntity" ) );
    }
}
```

Two things should be pointed out here:

- First, as the Mapstruct default implementation, your custom exclusion mapper should exclude all types under the `java` or `javax` packages. As indicated in the docs, this means that MapStruct will not try to generate an automatic sub-mapping method between some custom type and some type declared in the Java class library.
- Second, as explained again in the [docs](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#using-spi), to register the service your need to:

> To use a custom SPI implementation, it must be located in a separate JAR
> file together with a file named after the SPI (e.g.
> `org.mapstruct.ap.spi.AccessorNamingStrategy`) in `META-INF/services/` with
> the fully qualified name of your custom implementation as content (e.g.
> `org.mapstruct.example.CustomAccessorNamingStrategy`). This JAR file needs
> to be added to the annotation processor classpath (i.e. add it next to the
> place where you added the `mapstruct-processor` jar).

In your case it means to define a file named `org.mapstruct.ap.spi.MappingExclusionProvider` under `META-INF/services/` with the fully qualified name of your custom `MappingExclusionProvider`.

Comment: unfortunately, this provider is applied to all mappers in the project, as you said. And I need to exclude only for specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `@BeforeMapping` and `@AfterMapping` hooks ? The map will be done anyways, so perhaps is not the best solution, but no exclusion seems possible due to mapstruct features on exclusion and your requirement about applying only to some converters, but mapping can be done with non conflicting, i.e. null or empty values if those values are modified in any of the hooks. Here an example, source from mapstruct doc: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after

```
@Mapper
public abstract class VehicleMapper {
    @BeforeMapping
    protected void flushEntity(AbstractVehicle vehicle) {

    }

    @AfterMapping
    protected void fillTank(AbstractVehicle vehicle, @MappingTarget AbstractVehicleDto result) {
        result.fuelUp( new Fuel( vehicle.getTankCapacity(), vehicle.getFuelType() ) );
    }

    public abstract CarDto toCarDto(Car car);
}

// Generates something like this:
public class VehicleMapperImpl extends VehicleMapper {
    public CarDto toCarDto(Car car) {
        flushEntity( car );

        if ( car == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CarDto carDto = new CarDto();
        // attributes mapping ...

        fillTank( car, carDto );

        return carDto;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want mapstruct to pull entire database while mapping some complex object with many dependencies. Setting nulls at BeforeMappping is changing sources object, what should not happen in mapping. Setting nulls at AfterMapping is pointless as entire database is already pulled.